# Ubuntu 17.10 Change mac address

Tags: 17.10

I install 17.10 and try to change(spoof) mac address of cable network card. I try to change by graphic interface. I can't. I try to change by command
ip li ....
I can't. Ubuntu set hardware mac and prevent any changes.
How i can change? Why it TOO hard?

Comment: can you specify the command that you are using? `ip link set` command is working fine on 17.10

Comment: ip link set dev interface down
ip link set dev interface address XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
ip link set dev interface up

But, at XXI century using console for change mac it's "amazing"

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 network configuration is completely changed. It uses NetPlan. Have a look:
https://websiteforstudents.com/configuring-static-ips-ubuntu-17-10-servers/